# Chemistry of cereal in milk

Tags: bond, home-experiment

In a nearly finished bowl of oat cereal, why do the pieces of cereal stick together? I figure that since they are composed of starches it could be hydrogen bonding. Is this true or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surface tension, not hydrogen bonding, is the primary phenomenon which causes cereal rings such as Cheerios to adhere together while floating in milk.

The total linear perimeter of the 3-phase cereal-air-milk interface is minimized when pieces cling together.

Here are some links:

- http://www.livescience.com/9350-cereal-science-floating-objects-stick.html
- http://phys.org/news/2010-09-well-known-effect-breakfast-cereal-physicists.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheerios_effect